# Precomputing SVG text coordinates and width

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to write a program, which will build automatically a chart with
SVG from some data. In the chart there are several arrows with text.

Now I am confronted with a problem: How can I know the length of the
text in advance?? How long does the arrow have to be? The complete text
must be placed above the arrow.

Does anybody have an idea?? How can I know how much place the text will
need in the SVG??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at measuring dimensions of the text element's [bounding box](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable). You could consider making an element invisible, if you want to precompute.